# second io.connection() in socket.io does not fire connect event

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need to dyanmically change the server to which the client connects. So, in my case the client if first connect to a server with:

```
var $socket = io.connect("//serverA:5656");
```

and this successfully fires the event code:

```
$socket.on('connect', function(data) {
   alert('socket connected with id ' + $socket.id);
});
```

however, if later on the code I need to change the server to connect to with:

```
$socket = io.connect("//serverB:8900");
```

the connect event is not fired even though it seems to generate a new value for $socket.id but any emit from server to this socket does not go through.

I tried with several options for the new server connection such as:

```
$socket.disconnect(true);
$socket = io.connect("//serverB:8900");
$socket.io.reconnect();

$socket.disconnect();
$socket.removeAllListeners('connect');
io.sockets = {};
$socket = io.connect("//serverB:8900");

$socket = io.connect("//serverB:8900", {'forceNew': true});

$socket = io.connect("//serverB:8900", {'force new connection': true});
```

None of this (and any combination of them) worked out.

Comment: It looks like you don't ever set th e`connection` event listener again, correct? `io.connect` creates a new object, which you have never called `.on('connection', ...)` on, so it it doesn't have a `connection` listener.

Comment: where should I set that? on the client? could you point to code sample please? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`io.connect` creates a new socket object. You create your first socket object when you call `io.connect("//serverA:5656")`. Then, you set a `connect` event listener on that socket.

You create a totally new socket when you call `io.connect("//serverB:8900")`. This new socket object doesn't know anything about the first socket you made previously. Importantly, it does not have a `connect` event listener.

You need to call `.on('connect', ...)` again, on the second socket object, to make it have a `connection` listener as well. Generally, every time you call `io.connection`, you need to make a subsequent call to `on` to attack a `connection` listener. You can put this operation in a single function to make it easier:

```
function makeSocketWithListener(server) {
    var socket = io.connect(server);
    socket.on("connect", function() {
        alert('socket connected with id ' + socket.id);
    });
    return socket;
}
```

var $socket = makeSocketWithListener("//serverA:5656");

...

var $socket = makeSocketWithListener("//serverB:8900");

Comment: this is working BUT it does not work if the server change is made inside a function. for instance in $$('#login').on('click', function () { $socket = makeSocketWithListener("//serverC:6900"); } does not fire the socket.on('connect')